# Spring Annotation Configs - dynamically create classes based on YAML config

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring annotations.

I have the following YAML configuration:

```
configLists: 
  - listItem1
  - listItem2
mainConfig:
  listItem1:
    listingName: listItem1
    property1: testing-value-1
    property2: testing-value-2
    storageprop: example/storage/loc-2

  listItem2:
    listingName: listItem2
    property1: testing-value-1
    property2: testing-value-2
    storageprop: example/storage/loc-2
```

With the help of Spring Annotations and configuration, I would like to create the classes dynamically. i.e. As there are two configurations under mainConfig listItem1 and listItem2 the application should create two instances with the help of single class only.

How I can make the use of @Bean, @Configuration, and other annotations in the Spring boot application?

Is it possible to pass the configuration at runtime to the class while creating the instances?

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks,

Avinash Deshmukh

Comment: A little hard to follow what you're asking for, maybe it's the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation?

Comment: Hi Andy, probably yes. This can be used to load the properties. However, based on the type of YAML config just want to understand is it possible to create the objects dynamically.

Comment: do you want to create Spring-beans from the YAML configuration or just need to get access to the properties in the code, so that you can inject and use it?

Comment: @Sindbad90 I want to create the Spring-beans from the YAML configuration dynamically. I hope it is possible to do that with Spring annotations.

Comment: modified my answer below, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

Create a simple bean class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` as follows:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("mainConfig")
public class AppProperties {

  private Map<String, ListItem> listItems;

  public static class ListItem {

    private String listingName;
    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private String storageProp;

    // setters, getters
  }

  // setters, getters
}
```

Now, I'm assuming you just want to get access to the distinct "listItem" properties in the code, by probably injecting it.

Create beans in a configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
class AppConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private AppProperties appProperties;

  @Bean("listItem1")
  public ListItem useListItem1() {
    return appProperties.getListItems().get("listItem1");
  }

  @Bean("listItem2")
  public ListItem useListItem2() {
    return appProperties.getListItems().get("listItem2");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! However, accessing the properties through the AppProperties is one way to get the properties and assign them. But, what if I add one more entry to the YAML config. The application should be able to create the Spring-Beans with the help of annotations as well as the configurations.

Comment: Even if you do have that, how are you going to use it without knowing how many list items you have? Your code does have a dependency on that, right? Plus, why do you need them as beans? Won't it work if they are simple objects, since they just hold date and do no do anything?

Comment: `AppProperties` itself is a bean, so `appProperties.getListItems()` gives you the list of all the list items in your configuration. So, even if your code doesn't depend on each list item directly, you have access to a bean that holds all list items collectively.

Comment: Thanks, @Sindbad90. I will try to implement the AppConfigurations as per your suggestion.

Comment: let me know if you face issues implementing this.

Comment: Thanks, Sindbad90... 
With the help of your answer, I can now implement the dynamic creation of beans as per the requirement. Thanks again.

Avinash.

Comment: How about 'long', 'int' type?

Comment: Avinash & @priyank-sriv - can we make .get(listitem1) dynamic ? Using values ? If so please do let me know any sample. For me same kind of Yaml and following same approach. Looking to remove hardcoded values.